# ASP.NET MVC2 and Entity Framework 4 Generating Model from Database without duplicating Membership Models

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have an MVC 2 project where I recently consolidated the auto-generated membership/roles database with my primary database. I have an EF4 model generated from the primary database and it contains a table called Books. Now that I've consolidated the two, I setup relationships between Books and aspnet_Users so that I can see each user's books.

The problem is that I want to update my EF4 model so that it represents this relationship, but I want to keep all of the generated membership code.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: i've said it before and i'll say it again - don't map the membership tables. use the built in provider api.

Comment: @RPM1984: I'm trying not to map them. :)

Comment: Also, I don't think that the provider API would be elegant here. My books (and other tables with added relationships to aspnet_users) are in the database and mapped to my entity model. The only way I see this working is to use the provider API to store IDs which I can then use to lookup items in the database. That would be rather round-about and ugly. Is there a better way I should be using the provider API here?

Comment: If you've watched Rob Conery's MVC storefront, he does exactly that - stitching to marry up his data with user's in the membership schema. there is no other way - other than writing your own membership provider. interested to see what other people say though.

Comment: @Wesley, defining an FK constraint between `aspnet_Users` and 'Books` is another kind of mapping the membership tables, even if you don't put it in your EF model. What would happen if you changed to OpenID? Or Facebook/Twitter authentication? Or wanted the SQL Provider data in a separate DB?

Comment: @Craig, thanks, point taken. So what is the preferred solution if I don't map the membership tables? Do I just store a list of book IDs using the provider API, or should I actually create my own Users table and store an ID to it? The latter seems like the most flexible approach but I'm not sure if it's the best practice.

Comment: Creating your own Users table is fine. You can have a field for the user ID from the membership API.

Comment: 100% agree with Craig. Have your basic User table with domain-specific User information, and either store the Membership GUID, or the email address. Email address is good (if trackable), as this is what get's put into the forms auth cookie (most of the time), and is therefore relevant to both the membership provider AND your domain model.

Comment: Thanks guys, if one of you want to post the advice as an answer question, I'll mark it as accepted so I can close out the post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not map the membership tables. Store the GUID or email address in another table. See the question comments for the detailed answer. Thanks @RPM1984 and @Craig Stuntz.